# can anybody fix this problem on zooming with js plumb

Tags: javascript, css, jsplumb

I applied zoom property in my jsplumb chart and for that when I use CSS property 'zoom' it is working fine but when I apply zoom with transform property the container entirely transforms, not only the nodes inside it. Here is the function I used for transforming:-

this is the function I am calling:

```
setZoom(currentscale,plumb);
```

[pen for the problem](https://codepen.io/vishnuprasadkv55/pen/jJEaza)

change currentscale to 1.5 or above in line number 63 in js to recreate the issue

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this setZoom(currentScale,plumb, [0,0]);   Is this what you want?

Comment: thanks for a quick look out.. actually, the problem is the container itself is transforming with the transform property. [here is original snap] (https://www.pixelsbin.com/image/newwwscrn.NiUaP) thus restricting the movement of nodes outside the container